# Why maven looks for local dependency .pom in remote repo?

Tags: maven

I have my project PartnerLocator-Admin dependent on my other project PartnerLocator-PRM built and installed locally with maven.
However PartnerLocator-Admin build fails with message:

> Failed to execute goal on project PartnerLocator-Admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.se.pl:PartnerLocator-Admin:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.se.pl:PartnerLocator-PRM:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.se.pl:PartnerLocator-PRM:jar:1.0: **Failure to find com.se.pl:PartnerLocator:pom:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2** was cached in the local repository...

Here is how this dependency is defined:

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>PartnerLocator-PRM</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.se.pl</groupId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I can see `PartnerLocator-PRM-1.0.pom` in my local Maven repo, so why Maven is looking for it in central repo?

[image]

Comment: First there seemed to be no such artifact like you given [`PartnerLocator-PRM`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7CPartnerLocator-PRM) which means you have to delete the folder com/se/pl in your repository and retry your build. The problem is that you defined it as a dependency which does not exist. Are you using a repository manager within a company ?

Comment: @khmarbaise actually Maven should find the dependency in the local repository if it's correctly installed. If it is found it should not search for it in the central repository anymore.

Comment: @Michlis did you install your dependency into your local repository or did you just copy it?

Answer (score 0):

My projects are actually modules of parent project 'PartnerLocator'.

[image: Netbeans view of parent project]

The answer was all the time in error message: `"Failure to find com.se.pl:PartnerLocator:pom"` - it's looking for parent project pom and not the module I wanted to build. I am just setting up this project on my machine so `PartnerLocator` was never build.

**Solution:** Build initially parent project first to install it's pom file in local repository.